# Unable to configure office 365 in mail app in mac

Tags: macos

I tried entering details by following 
1) go to accounts option in mail app
2) entered credentials
3) entered incoming outgoing server as outllok.office365.com
Here it shows Done button and on click it converts to next button 
But when i tap on next button it doesnt proceed

I tried to clear cache from ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Caches/WebKit .
Whereas when I configured google mail and it works properly.